# Help with multi-lingual text, php, and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, multibyte

I have had no end of problems trying to do what I thought would be relatively simple:

I need to have a form which can accept user input text in a mix of English an other languages, some multi-byte (ie Japanese, Korean, etc), and this gets processed by php and is stored (safely, avoiding SQL injection) in a mysql database.  It also needs to be accessed from the database, processed, and used on-screen.

I have it set up fine for Latin chars but when I add a mix of Latin andmulti-byte chars it turns garbled.

I have tried to do my homework but just am banging my head against a wall now.

Magic quotes is off, I have tried using utf8_encode/decode, htmlentities, addslashes/stripslashes, and (in mysql) both "utf8_general_ci" and "utf8_unicode_ci" for the field in the table.

Part of the problem is that there are so many places where I could be messing it up that I'm not sure where to begin solving the problem.

Thanks very much for any and all help with this.  Ideally, if someone has working php code examples and/or knows the right mysql table format, that would be fantastic.

Comment: "Garbled" how? Looks bad in the database itself, or as you output it on a page? Are you specifying UTF-8 on your form and output pages? More details would be helpful if you want non-general answers.

Comment: Yes, good point.  Sorry.  I should explain:

Comment: Before the data is stored it is encrypted. When it is read, it is unencrypted.I see, for example, half of the data fine and then it hits something (such as an apostrophe or quote or kanji character or something) and it is garbled after that.  Maybe either incorrect escaping or incorrect encoding is causing the issue.  I _am_ able to see (or add with PhpMyAdmin) Japanese kanji or Korean hangul into the field.  So I _THINK_ my issue is in the problems with escapes of special chars.  Also, I am not sure if I'm specifying utf-8 on the form. How to do that?

Comment: Oh, using PhpMyAdmin adds another level of complexity to your problem solving because you will also be dealing with whatever encoding PhpMyAdmin is inflicting on the data.

Comment: You can specify the encoding with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` at the top of your HTML. You can also do `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in your Apache config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have any practical alternatives to UTF-8. You're going to have to track down where the encoding and/or decoding breaks. Start by checking whether you can round-trip multi-language text to the data base from the mysql command line, or perhaps through phpmyadmin. Track down and eliminate problems at that level. Then move out one more level by simulating input to your php and examining the output, again dealing with any problems. Finally add browsers into the mix.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll work on this step by step and see where it takes me.

Comment: I thought I was commenting here but put it above:  the round trip works.  The issue (possibly) is that when the data's stored, it's not stored in a human-readable format.  Maybe the php-mysql link is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a laundry list of things to check are in UTF8 mode:

- MySQL table encoding. You seem to have already done this.
- MySQL connection encoding. Do `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'char%'` and you will see what MySQL is using. You need `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection` and `character_set_results` set to `utf8` which can easily set in your application by doing `SET NAMES 'utf8'` at the start of all connections. *This is the one most people forget to check, IME.*
- If you use them, your CLI and terminal settings. In bash, this means `LANG=(something).UTF-8`.
- Your source code (this is not usually a problem unless you have UTF8 constant text).
- The page encoding. You seem to have this one right, too, but your browsers debug tools can help a lot.

Once you get all this right, all you will need in your app is `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Oh and it *is* (sadly) possible to successfully store correctly encoded UTf8 text in a column with the wrong encoding type or from a connection with the wrong encoding type. And it can come back "correctly", too. Until you fix all the bits that aren't UTF8, at which point it breaks.

Comment: This is a very useful list.  I think actually I've got these all set correctly, but now I'm realizing that (I think) there's a problem with the escaping of the data.  Because when I run a test harness that doesn't store to mysql, I have no problems -- it encrypts and decrypts just fine.  If I store data without encrypting, it's fine.  If I encrypt and store data that's less than a line, it's fine.  But if I type a longer sentence and the line wraps, the encryption breaks.  Not always at that exact linebreak, but it always breaks.

Comment: You **should** be able to treat UTF8 data just like any text. If you are or have to put it through any *encoding* steps (this is very different from *encryption*), then you have a problem somewhere. Once everything has the same character set, then you will **only** need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if you can add multi-language text to your database directly. If its possible you can do it in your application

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible.  Sometimes random multi-lingual text is stored in the data and I can add it (and it stays formatted correctly).

Comment: I think you will be confused in how to manage multiple languages from the front end?.

Comment: Possibly.  I wrote in another comment that there seems to be an issue when the data's uploaded into Mysql.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you serializing any data by chance?  PHPs serialize function has some issue when serializing non-english characters.

Everything you do should be [utf-8 encoded](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#44272).

One thing you could try is to [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the data when putting it into the database and [json_decoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it when it's retrieved.

Comment: Yes, but how do I make sure everything is UTF-8 encoded?  Do I use utf8_encode for my stings?  What syntax?

Comment: The first link above has an example for setting UTF-8 charset for your php handling scripts `header('charset=utf-8');` (if you have a config file then put it there) and for your html content `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`  (html5 is like this: `<meta charset="utf-8">` ).  For mysql use `utf8_general_ci` for your tables.

Comment: Okay, so...it kind of works:  I can enter text in any language, click "submit", it goes into the database, I can go to the page where I pull the data back out and sure enough, it works -- it's retained, all the languages are there.  BUT the data is garbled when I view it in PhpMyAdmin.  I am using utf8_general_ci, but I don't see anything that's human readable.  If I edit the data by hand, I can input Japanese or Korean and see it in the table.  But not when it's uploaded via php.  Does this sound like the root of my issue?

Comment: @Dave, If you are json_encoding it the Japanese or Korean characters won't show like they are editable you will see something like `\u00e1` which if you wanted to edit it through phpMyAdmin you would need to replace it with the encoded characters themselves.  I personally don't use phpMyAdmin that much.  If you are not json_encoding is phpMyAdmin setup for the right encoding type? It would need to be UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection settings. It also needs to support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by my not having the default char set in the php.ini file, and (possibly) not having set the char set in the mysql table (in PhpMyAdmin, via the Operations tab).

Setting the default char set to "utf-8" fixed it.  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I now have a different issue, which is that somehow I need to properly escape line breaks that are caused by wordwrap in the text area.